# Slow First call rest API springboot Jersey Eureka

Tags: performance, rest, spring-boot, jersey, netflix-eureka

My application is a `Rest` API `springboot` `+jersey` based on microservice architecture `Eureka`.

The first call after instance start is slow comparing to the following calls (even though I stubbed the results).

Example of first call: 500ms, the other calls about 60-100ms.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello Faroukb, Welcome to StackOverflow. I have improved you question in adding new lines and in highlighting some nouns. You can edit again to see how to do next time. Can you put some code so that we can have some idea about your problem ?

Comment: By default the application is not fully initialized on startup. You need to set the [load-on-startup](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5100) property. Did you already set this?

Comment: Yes I did it ,but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this is related to JVM warm up. From https://www.baeldung.com/java-jvm-warmup:

> The first request made to a Java web application is often substantially slower than the average response time during the lifetime of the process. This warm-up period can usually be attributed to lazy class loading and just-in-time compilation.

Comment: thank you Wim, but there is not a solution to do this initialization when starting the spring boot application...

Comment: I don't think it is related to JVM loading classes. Spring instantiates all beans during start-up. Instead, I believe it is related to how message parsers are only created the first time they are needed. See my similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69760176/324531 for further details.

Comment: In my case, the DB connection pool was taking time for initialization on first request.

I have added minpoolsize=10 in database string, now the first request is as quick as the subsequent requests.

The default minpoolsize is 0.