# How to initialize Jackson on Spring Boot start to have fast 1st request?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

### Problem

I have a simple Spring Boot app with a basic RestController ([full code available here](https://github.com/steinsag/warm-me-up)). It consumes JSON and uses Jackson to convert request from JSON and response to JSON.

```
@RestController("/")
@RequestMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<SomeResponseDto> post(@RequestBody @Valid SomeRequestDto someRequestDto) {
        final SomeResponseDto responseDto = new SomeResponseDto();
        responseDto.setMessage(someRequestDto.getInputMessage());
        responseDto.setUuid(someService.getUuid());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseDto);
    }
```

After start-up, the 1st request is about 10-times slower than any sub-sequent request. I debugged and profiled the app and it seems that on first request a Jackson JSON parser is getting initialized somewhere in [AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java#L146) and [AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java).

In sub-sequent requests, it seems to get re-used.

### Question

**How do I initialize Jackson JSON parsing during start-up so that also 1st request is fast?**

I know how to trigger a method after Spring started. In [PreloadComponent](https://github.com/steinsag/warm-me-up/blob/main/src/main/java/services/progressit/warmmeup/initialization/PreloadComponent.java) I added as an example how to do a REST request against the controller.

```
@Component
public class PreloadComponent implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PreloadComponent.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        // uncomment following line to directly send a REST request on app start-up
//        sendRestRequest();
    }

    private void sendRestRequest() {
        final String serverPort = environment.getProperty("local.server.port");
        final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + serverPort;
        final String warmUpEndpoint = baseUrl + "/warmup";

        logger.info("Sending REST request to force initialization of Jackson...");

        final SomeResponseDto response = webClientBuilder.build().post()
                .uri(warmUpEndpoint)
                .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .body(Mono.just(createSampleMessage()), SomeRequestDto.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(SomeResponseDto.class)
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .block();

        logger.info("...done, response received: " + response.toString());
    }

    private SomeRequestDto createSampleMessage() {
        final SomeRequestDto someRequestDto = new SomeRequestDto();
        someRequestDto.setInputMessage("our input message");

        return someRequestDto;
    }
}
```

This only works in this toy example. In reality, I have many REST endpoints with complex DTOs and I would need to add a "warm-up" endpoint next to each "real" endpoint as I can't call my real endpoints.

### What I already tried?

I added a second endpoint with a different DTO and called it in my `PreloadComponent`. This doesn't solve the problem. I assume that an Jackson / whatever instance is created for each type.

I autowired `ObjectMapper` into my `PreloadComponent` and parsed JSON to my DTO. Again, this doesn't solve the issue.

Full source available at: https://github.com/steinsag/warm-me-up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that Jackson validation is the problem. I added the JVM option

```
-verbose:class
```

to see when classes get loaded. I noticed that on 1st request, there are many Jackson validation classes getting loaded.

To confirm my assumption, I re-worked my example and added another independent [warm-up controller](https://github.com/steinsag/warm-me-up/blob/main/src/main/java/services/progressit/warmmeup/initialization/WarmUpController.java) with a [distinct DTO](https://github.com/steinsag/warm-me-up/blob/main/src/main/java/services/progressit/warmmeup/initialization/WarmUpRequestDto.java).

This DTO uses all Java validation annotations also present like in the [real DTO](https://github.com/steinsag/warm-me-up/blob/main/src/main/java/services/progressit/warmmeup/rest/dto/SomeRequestDto.java), e.g. `@NotNull`, `@Min`, etc. In addition, it also has a custom enum to also have validation of sub-types.

During start-up, I now do a REST request to this warm-up endpoint, which doesn't need to contain any business logic.

After start-up, my **1st request is now only 2-3 times slower** than any sub-sequent requests. This is is acceptable. Before, the 1st request was 20-40 times slower.

I also evaluated if really a REST request is needed or if it is sufficient to just do JSON parsing or validation of a DTO (see [PreloadComponent](https://github.com/steinsag/warm-me-up/blob/main/src/main/java/services/progressit/warmmeup/initialization/PreloadComponent.java)). This reduces runtime of 1st request a bit, but it is still 5-15 times slower than with proper warm-up. So I guess a REST request is needed to also load other classes in Spring Dispatcher, etc.

I updated my example at: https://github.com/steinsag/warm-me-up

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that a lot of classes will be lazy-loaded. If first call performance is important, then I think warming up by calling each endpoint is the way to go.

Why do you say, that you cannot call the endpoints? If you have a database and you don't want to change the data, wrap everything in a transaction and roll it back after the warm up calls.

I haven't seen any other method to solve this, which doesn't necessarily mean, that it doesn't exist ;)

Comment: The call has to come from the outside, i.e. via REST. Therefore, I would need to send some kind of ignore header or hidden attribute to prevent any state changes in my service. Thing is that there is not just a database, but also Kafka messages being send and other systems getting called :-/

Comment: I think adding @Transactional and rolling it back after the calls should work. I am not sure how spring does that, but I have used something similar before. Doesn't help you with the messages though :/